# ORA-22835: Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR... error when trying to render Dynamic PL/SQL Content Region - APEX 21.2

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an Interactive Report that links to a Course Details modal page. The Course Details page has a single Region [Type: PL/SQL Dynamic Content] that uses a SQL query as it's source. The SQL returns embedded HTML from a column of type CLOB. When trying to render the modal page, I sometimes get the following error:

```
ERROR: ORA-22835: Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW conversion (actual: 4270, maximum: 4000)
Error: Error during rendering of region "Course Details".
```

I am figuring that even though I am returning a CLOB, the APEX engine is converting it into a VARCHAR2 or something when rendering the region and is running out of buffer space on certain records.

***UPDATE:***
I think I figured out that the error is happening due to the fact that I am returning the HTML_CLOB data using `htp.p`. So that is where it is converting the CLOB to a VARCHAR2/CHAR and throwing the error. What is alternative to `htp.p(l_html_clob)`?

Guessing I need to loop through the CLOB data and return in 4000 byte chuncks.

This is a sample of the HTML output that is dynamically generated and returned:

```html
<div class="course-output">
    <div class="course-hide-content" course-subtitle-original>Level 1</div>
    <div class="course-hide-content" course-group-others></div>
    <div class="course-details">
        <div class="course-group-name">Fine Arts: Music</div>
        <div class="title-number">Intermediate Band (923310)</div>
        <div class="course-subtitle"></div>
        <div class="course-metadata">
            <div class="course-meta-data-row"><span>Grades:</span><span>7, 8</span></div>
            <div class="course-meta-data-row"><span>Credits:</span><span>non-credit</span></div>
            <div class="course-meta-data-row"><span>Academic Type:</span><span>None Listed</span></div>
            <div class="course-meta-data-row"><span>Prerequisite:</span><span>Successful audition</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="course-description">
        <span class="course-description">Intermediate level band students will continue to
            develop skills on woodwind, brass, or percussion instruments. A variety of musical styles will be studied
            through the playing of band literature. Students must meet both the school day and outside of the school day
            participation requirements to receive credit for the course. This course requires a student materials fee as
            listed in FCPS Notice 5922.</span>
        <span course-description-append></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help in pointing me in the correct direction.

Comment: try minifying the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the clob and print in chunks of 4000 characters - that shouldn't error out. Here is sample code. Note that `htp.prn` is what you need, not `htp.p`. The latter prints a newline character after the string and that could produce unexpected results and hours of bug hunting...

```
DECLARE
  l_clob  CLOB;
  l_query VARCHAR2(32000);
  l_amt   INTEGER := 4000;
  l_pos   INTEGER := 1;
  l_buf   VARCHAR2(4000);  
BEGIN
  l_query := <your_query>;
  
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_query INTO l_clob;
  LOOP
      BEGIN
      dbms_lob.read(
                  l_clob,
                  l_amt,
                  l_pos,
                  l_buf
      );
      l_pos := l_pos + l_amt;
      -- need htp.prn since htp.p generates a newline char at the end.
      htp.prn(l_buf);
      EXCEPTION
      WHEN no_data_found THEN
          EXIT;
      END;
  END LOOP;  
END;
```

Comment: Hey Koen, I tried above and still getting the error. Does it matter that my database setting is set to MAX_STRING_SIZE = STANDARD? That should still allow me to use 4000 byte buffer, correct?

Comment: Also, does it matter that the query I am selecting from is using a view (not a table) and the 'html_code' column is a virtual column is generated in that view? Looking at the view in Toad, it says that 'html_code' is type CLOB.

Comment: Not sure about the MAX_STRING_SIZE but... how exactly did you implement this ? The code I posted works fine for me - did you put exactly that code in the source for the pl/sql region ?

Comment: What is the exact line the error is thrown on ? You could sprinkle some ```apex_debug``` statements and an ```EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS``` block to figure out where exactly it errors out

Comment: Yes, I have done that and is how I saw the error I posted above:

APPLICATION ERROR:
    LOCATION: ccp_course.view_course_details_html
    ERROR: ORA-22835: Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW conversion (actual: 4270, maximum: 4000)
    BACKTRACE: ORA-06512: at "COURSE_CATALOG_APP.CCP_COURSE", line 39

I did further testing & error is happening when trying to fetch the view's html_clob column into l_html_code clob variable in the SQL. So makes me wonder if that view's virtual column is actually a clob? I ended up building the html in the procedure instead of the view. Thx

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't see your code. Move the code out of the package and into the pl/sql dynamic region, just for testing and use just the code above. Then check where it errors out. Isolate the problem out of your packaged code since that is impossible for me to diagnose.

Comment: I did that as well and still hit the error. When I comment out the sql statement that fetches the clob and just output some test code it works. when I uncomment the sql statement (even if not trying to render the clob) it still throws the error, which is why i think the issue is in the select into statement. Which is why I am wondering if view's virtual column is actually a CLOB datatype or if Toad is just displaying it like that instead of actually a VARCHAR2(4000) in view. I agree your solution should work, but think it is due to database setup & view. Appreciate your help